# How to use href attribute and asp-controller/asp-action in a anchor tag? [asp.net core mvc]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Anchor tag:

```
<a class="nav-link active"  href="javascript:void(0);" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile"><i class="bx bx-user me-1"></i> Profile</a>
```

Following error occurs:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot override the 'href' attribute for
> . An  with a specified 'href' must not have attributes starting
> with 'asp-route-' or an 'asp-action', 'asp-controller', 'asp-area',
> 'asp-route', 'asp-protocol', 'asp-host', 'asp-fragment', 'asp-page' or
> 'asp-page-handler' attribute.

I understand why error occured its because href attribute can not be used with asp-controller/asp-action attributes.
i am using a UI template with builtin js functions so i have to use href="javascript:void(0);" for js to perform somr functionality as well as move to another page in MVC using asp-controller/asp-action attributes.

Comment: `asp-controller="Home"` and `asp-action="Profile"` will generate the href attribute of the anchor, in this case `href="/Home/Profile"`. If you overwrite the href to `href="javascript:void(0);"` then the link will no longer point to the Profile action of Home controller.

Comment: I know this but my problem is different as I have explained in the question I need a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using a UI template with builtin js functions so i have to use
> href="javascript:void(0);" for js to perform somr functionality as
> well as move to another page in MVC using asp-controller/asp-action
> attributes.

Well, in asp.net core you would seen [@Html.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rendering-htmlhelperlinkextensions-actionlink(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rendering-ihtmlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object-system-object)) within  [HtmlHelperLinkExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class which as action and controller along with htmlAttributes together which would generate an anchor () element. You could have look below reference:

[image]

Implementation:

You can using [@Html.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rendering-htmlhelperlinkextensions-actionlink(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rendering-ihtmlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object-system-object)) overload method either in following way:

**Way: 1**

```
@Html.ActionLink("<a><a/>Anchor Tag Using Action Link  Profile", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { @href="javascript:void(0);", @onclick = "return Submit()" })
```

**Note:** You can directly call javascript function as well. As you can see I am calling by Submit() which is a self define function.

**Way: 2**

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "<a><a/>Anchor Tag Using Action Link  Profile",
    "MemberList",
    "Animal",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    new { @href="javascript:void(0);", @onclick = "return Submit()" })
```

**Note:** You could modify as per your requirement and this would allow you to combine javascript:void(0) along with controller and action what you are trying to achieve.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on numerous [ActionLink overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rendering-htmlhelperlinkextensions-actionlink(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rendering-ihtmlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-object-system-object)) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your customize ***html a tag*** as **tag helper**, and use it instead of normal ***a html tag***.

for example:

```
namespace Web.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("MyHref")]
    public class MyHrefTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public string Controller { get; set; } = "";
        public string Action { get; set; } = "";
        public string Class { get; set; } = "";
        public string Href{ get; set; } = "";

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "a";
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", $"{Class}");

            //here you can make decision to use asp-for or href or whatever you want to do
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Href) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Href))
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", $"/{controller}/{Action}");
            else
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", $"{Href}");
         }
    }
}
```

---

```
 <MyHref class="nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0);" controller="Home" action="Profile">Profile</MyHref>
```

remember you should add your tagHelper namespace in **_ViewImports.cshtml** :

```
@addTagHelper *, Web
```

Comment: When href attribute is defined your tag helper ignores the controller and action attributes, so what is the benefit to use this tag helper instead of simply `<a class="nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0);">Profile</a>`?

Comment: As he said **"i have to use href="javascript:void(0);" for js to perform somr functionality"**.

Comment: He said he wants both `href="javascript:void(0);"` and `asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Profile"` attributes in order "to perform some functionality **as well as move to another page**". With your tag helper it won't move to another page.

Comment: You are right 